# Can Python log with different formatters to the same file

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to log into a single file using two different Formatters. The use-case for this is to get a file that looks like this:

```
+-------------------+
| Setup the servers |
+-------------------+
2018-10-10 17:24:33,891 [INFO] - func=test_01_pass:[7] - location=debug_tests.py - MSG=Doing something with servers

+---------------------------------------------------+
| Login to sdc with user: cs0008 & password: 123456 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
2018-10-10 17:24:33,892 [INFO] - func=test_01_pass:[11] - location=debug_tests.py - MSG=Doing something to login

+----------------+
| Create Service |
+----------------+
2018-10-10 17:24:33,892 [INFO] - func=test_01_pass:[14] - location=debug_tests.py - MSG=Doing create service flow

+----------------------+
| Teardown the servers |
+----------------------+
2018-10-10 17:24:33,893 [INFO] - func=test_01_pass:[17] - location=debug_tests.py - MSG=Doing something to teardown the servers
```

Where log.info() uses a formatter with a timestamp etc., while another log I created log.step() uses a formatter without a timestamp.

When defining two streamHandlers that write to sys.stdout, the output of the code:

```
logger.step('Create Service')
logger.info('Doing create service flow')

logger.step('Teardown the servers')
logger.info('Doing something to teardown the servers')
```

looks OK, as seen in the first snippet above.

However, when using the two fileHandlers that write to the same log, the output is garbled up:

```
2018-10-10 17:24:33,891 [INFO] - func=test_01_pass:[7] - location=d
+-----------------------------------------------2018-10-10 17:24:33,892 [INFO] - func=test_01_pass:[11] - location=debug_tests.py - MSG=Doing something to login
2018-10-10 17:24:33,892 [INFO] - func=test_01_pass:[14] - l
+----------------------+
| Teardown the servers |
+---2018-10-10 17:24:33,893 [INFO] - func=test_01_pass:[17] - location=debug_tests.py - MSG=Doing something to teardown the servers
```

Is there a way to write to the **same** log file using **two different formatters**?

**------ Additional Info ------**

I found a solution [How to use different formatters with the same logging handler in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741972/how-to-use-different-formatters-with-the-same-logging-handler-in-python) that allows to change the formatter depending on the dispatcher, i.d. which module is writing it. I am trying to modify the class **DispatchingFormatter** from that solution to select the formatter depending on the message severity level.

Comment: Have you tried changing the formatter on the fly ?

Comment: That's what I am going to try and implement using the "DispatchingFormatter" example from the solution I mention above. I do hope for a simpler solution.